# Run multiple Gulp Tasks asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, gulp, taskmanager

I have an Array of gulp task:

```
var tasks = ['task1','task2','task3'];
```

if i start my following gulp task, it will run all tasks in my tasks array, but at the same time.

```
gulp.start('mytasks', tasks, function(){});
```

Is there a way to run my tasks from the tasks array asynchronously ?

Comment: NodeJS is single threaded, so the task that run "at the same time" are effectively running "asynchronously".

Answer (score 1):

Gulp is promise based and by default asynchronous .
Quoting from the official [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support):

> Tasks can be made asynchronous if its fn does one of the following:
>
> - Return a stream
> - Return a promise
> - Accept a callback

Take a look at this example which emulates the behaviour mentioned above.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    wait = require('gulp-wait');

var tasks = ["task1","task2","task3"]

gulp.task('mytasks', function() {
  return gulp.src("/dist")
        .pipe(wait(5))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH'));
});

gulp.task('task1', function() {
  return gulp.src("/dist")
        .pipe(wait(100))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH'));
});

gulp.task('task2', function() {
  return gulp.src("/dist")
        .pipe(wait(200))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH'));
});


gulp.task('task3', function() {
  return gulp.src("/dist")
        .pipe(wait(50))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('mytasks', tasks, function(){});
});
```